# Recorded CodedUI can't find recorded Controls

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

So I've gone and used the Code generator in Visual Studio to generate a coded UI test.  We have a wpf application with an TreeList.  I record it going to the first box, entering in a value, then clicking in the second box, and it types in a new value.  Nothing super fancy.

```
public void RecordedMethod1()
{
    #region Variable Declarations
    WpfCell uIItemCell = this.UIWindowWindow.UIEntityTesterControlCustom.UIEntityTesterTreeListTree.UIEntityTesterTreeListTreeItem.UIItemCell;
    WpfEdit uIInvoice1InvoiceIDEdiEdit = this.UIWindowWindow.UIEntityTesterControlCustom.UIEntityTesterTreeListTree.UIEntityTesterTreeListTreeItem.UIItemCell.UIInvoice1InvoiceIDEdiEdit;
    WpfCell uIItemCell1 = this.UIWindowWindow.UIEntityTesterControlCustom.UIEntityTesterTreeListTree.UIEntityTesterTreeListTreeItem.UIItemCell1;
    WpfEdit uI_localTextBoxEdit = this.UIWindowWindow.UIEntityTesterControlCustom.UIEntityTesterTreeListTree.UIEntityTesterTreeListTreeItem.UIItemCell11.UI_localTextBoxEdit;
    #endregion

    // Click cell
    Mouse.Click(uIItemCell, new Point(92, 18));

    // Type '1' in 'Invoice:1/InvoiceID|Editor' text box
    uIInvoice1InvoiceIDEdiEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UIInvoice1InvoiceIDEdiEditText;

    // Click cell
    Mouse.Click(uIItemCell1, new Point(136, 9));

    // Type '2/1/2012' in '_localTextBox' text box
    uI_localTextBoxEdit.Text = this.RecordedMethod1Params.UI_localTextBoxEditText;
}

#region Properties
public virtual RecordedMethod1Params RecordedMethod1Params
{
    get
    {
        if ((this.mRecordedMethod1Params == null))
        {
            this.mRecordedMethod1Params = new RecordedMethod1Params();
        }
        return this.mRecordedMethod1Params;
    }
}
```

It crashes with this error on the first Mouse.Click() call

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException was unhandled by user code
HResult=-268111872
Message=The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
TechnologyName:  'UIA'
FrameworkId:  'Wpf'
ControlType:  'Custom'
ClassName:  'Uia.EntityTesterControl'
AutomationId:  'EntityTesterControl'
Search may have failed at 'Test Suite Tools' Custom as it may have virtualized children. If the control being searched is descendant of 'Test Suite Tools' Custom then including it as the parent container may solve the problem.
Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting
BasicMessage=The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties.
RootElement=""
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapControlNotFoundException(COMException ex, IPlaybackContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, IPlaybackContext context)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, String queryId)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetUITestControlRecursive(Boolean useCache, Boolean alwaysSearch, ISearchArgument searchArg, IList`1 windowTitles, Int32& timeLeft)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument searchArg)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindPrivate()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<Find>b__37()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.Find()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetPropertyPrivate(String propertyName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c__DisplayClass3b.<GetProperty>b__3a()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.GetProperty(String propertyName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ALUtility.GetTechElementFromUITestControl(UITestControl uiTestControl)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ActionExecutorManager.GetActionExecutor(UITestControl uiControl)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.ClickImplementation(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.<>c__DisplayClass6.<Click>b__5()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl control, MouseButtons button, ModifierKeys modifierKeys, Point relativeCoordinate)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Mouse.Click(UITestControl control, Point relativeCoordinate)
at RoadExercises.UIMap.RecordedMethod1() in c:\Users\dtan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\UIMap.Designer.cs:line 46
at RoadExercises.RoadExercises.IrVerifyFillInField(String p1, String p2) in c:\Users\dtan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\RoadExercises.cs:line 169
at RoadExercises.RoadExercises.RoadExercise1b() in c:\Users\dtan\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUITestProject1\CodedUITestProject1\RoadExercises.cs:line 139
InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
HResult=-2147467259
Message=Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback
ErrorCode=-2147467259
StackTrace:
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.FindAllDescendants(String bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindAllScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean singleQueryId, Boolean throwException, Boolean resetSkipStep)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean resetSkipStep)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
InnerException:
```

As far as I can tell (when I did various slow steps/null checks).  The control for UIEntityTesterTreeListTree can't be found.  It looks like it's not located under the path that was mapped.  Apparently the path for this isn't a simple case of UIWindowWindow.UIEntityTesterControlCustom.UIEntityTesterTree, but instead there's a few more sub areas it has to go through before then.

I've tried to remap it a few times, but no luck.  I'd rather not hard code it, so hoping someone here can help me find the issue/way to fix this.

Thanks!

Comment: Web searching for part of the error message gives lots of hits. The first result I got on searching for "Search may have failed as it may have virtualized children" is a Microsoft blog (by Tapas) with an explanation of the message and a workaround.

Comment: tried his solution @AdrianHHH by adding this line into the code after it declares the WpfCell/WpfEdit  

`this.UIWindowWindow.UIEntityTesterControlCustom.Container = this.UIWindowWindow.UIPART_DockSitePane.UITabbedMdiContainer2fPane;`  
  
No dice.  it still crashed like it did before as it's unable to find elements :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to edit the search properties of the WpfCell to be sure that they're using correct values.  The Coded UI Test Builder can often be too specific to work all the time, and I've found that editing the values down to the least common denominator is the best practice.   [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269469.aspx)  a good place to start.

I don't have much experience modifying the search properties to look for locations in the tree by position, as I've found it makes the code more complicated and isn't always, in my experience, very stable.  If some element gets added or moved in development, it will break all of your code and you'll have to go back and change the parameters for all of your mappings.  My suggestion would be to have the developer add an identifying property (unique name tag, for instance) to the elements so that you can specify that in your search instead.

If you're comfortable with c#, it may be easier to code your mapping instead.  If you have a specific property for the element, that will make it easier, of course.  For example:

```
<wpfelement>
    <subElement name='someElement'>
        <button name='oneButton'>Click me.</button>
    </subElement>
</wpfelement>
<wpfelement>
    <subElement name='someOtherElement'>
        <button name='secondButton'>Click me.</button>
    </subElement>
</wpfelement>
```

would be found in your map by:

```
public WpfButton UIItemCell
{
    get
    {
        WfpButton target = new WpfButton(parentElement);
        target.SearchProperties["name"] = "secondButton";
        return target;
    }
}
```

This way, no matter where the element is in your tree, the Coded UI engine will find it with ease.  If there aren't any identifying properties for the cell you want, it would be helpful to add them to the UI, but you can also navigate from the closest parent that has an identifier using `element.GetChildren()` and filtering from there.

Comment: Have you ever modified the Coded UI Mappings to locate things deeper and vertically in the tree before?  It looks like my object is at a different level than the code is looking, but also a few branches over.

So it's looks for the item in node[1].[3] when the item it wants is really in node[2].[1].[4]  any ideas how I can change the properties to locate it?  Trying to avoid having the code check up/down the entire tree.  I know it's in node[2].[1].[4], but I don't know how to move the search from node[1].[3] to node[2].[1].[4]

Comment: I edited the answer.  Let me know if it's not clear.